# How to extract image from the url below

Tags: python-3.x, image, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the image url from the website.

The problem is, when I inspect the page. The image tag is in the following hierarchy.

```
a div div div img
```

but when I extract the a tag, no div tags are displayed in the console.

I tried to get the img tag directly from the page, but it still doesn't work. find all returns empty.

```
containers = page_soup.findAll("li",{"class":"result-row"})
```

containers[0].a //returns the a tag without any divs whereas divs are displayed inside the inspect

the a.div returns empty. and a.div.div returns an error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ePxU.png)

https://cairo.craigslist.org/d/apts-housing-for-rent/search/apa

Answer (score 0):

The gallery is created through Javascript, so Beautiful Soup doesn't see the images. But the components to construct the image urls are inside the document:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://cairo.craigslist.org/d/apts-housing-for-rent/search/apa'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

img_url = 'https://images.craigslist.org/{}_300x300.jpg'
# img_url = 'https://images.craigslist.org/{}_1200x900.jpg' <--- for high resolution images
for i, (a_img, a_title) in enumerate(zip(soup.select('.result-row a.result-image.gallery[data-ids]'),
                          soup.select('.result-row a.result-title')), 1):
    print('** Apartment no.{} **'.format(i))
    print('Title:', a_title.text.strip())
    print('Url:', a_title['href'])
    print('Pictures:')
    for data_id in [s.split(':')[1] for s in a_img['data-ids'].split(',')]:
        print(img_url.format(data_id))
    print('*' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
** Apartment no.1 **
Title: Furnished Apartment at Prime Location (3877)
Url: https://cairo.craigslist.org/apa/d/furnished-apartment-at-prime-location/6938106019.html
Pictures:
https://images.craigslist.org/00h0h_hHtQH46aGDx_300x300.jpg
https://images.craigslist.org/00E0E_c6LdyvFNQpw_300x300.jpg
https://images.craigslist.org/00j0j_azISDbP8lYF_300x300.jpg
https://images.craigslist.org/00l0l_fzEJ599vi7F_300x300.jpg
********************************************************************************
** Apartment no.2 **
Title: very nice apartment for rent in maadi saryaat
Url: https://cairo.craigslist.org/apa/d/very-nice-apartment-for-rent-in-maadi/6939574547.html
Pictures:
https://images.craigslist.org/00x0x_4fUU2oK8Y5k_300x300.jpg
https://images.craigslist.org/00U0U_1j56IqYoVLl_300x300.jpg
https://images.craigslist.org/00V0V_205pNGQoHQb_300x300.jpg
https://images.craigslist.org/00404_9NnufnHy4en_300x300.jpg
https://images.craigslist.org/00V0V_8BIpoHBxxOp_300x300.jpg
https://images.craigslist.org/00B0B_kIbSEBeqzNq_300x300.jpg
https://images.craigslist.org/00606_6yqxKan7ysg_300x300.jpg
********************************************************************************

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help dude! 

I am running into another issue while writing these urls to images. I'm getting a failed connection error. maybe because there are so many images. The script crashes after 3 images saying 

urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021CB930EDC8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

Please guide. Thanks in advance

Comment: @MustafaAslam I would for example wait between downloading each image some small period of time - 1 or 2 sec. Or download only first image for each apartment.